# A general Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Let $R$ be a ring. If $I_1,\ldots, I_k$ are ideals of $R$ and for all $i$:
>
> $$I_i + \bigcap_{j\neq i} I_j = R$$
>
> then for all $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in R$, there exists some $a \in R$ such that for all $i$, $a \equiv a_i \pmod{I_i}$

I could prove this for $k=2$: for $a_1,a_2 \in R$, $a_1 - a_2 \in I_1 + I_2$, so there are $i_i \in I_i$ such that $a_1 - a_2 = -i_1  + i_2$. Hence $a_1 + i_1 = a_2 + i_2 = a$, and $a \equiv a_i \pmod{I_i}$ for $i=1,2$.

I couldn't prove the general case. Any help?

Comment: Where did you find this proposition?

Comment: @Xam exercise $10$, page $110$ in N.Jacobson's Basic Algebra 1 (2nd edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for the inductive step:**

Suppose $I_1,\dots, I_k,I_{k+1}$ are ideals in $R$ such that for any $1\le i \le k+1$, 
$$I_i+\bigcap_{\substack{1\le j \le k+1\\j\ne i}}I_j=R. $$

Then, *a fortiori*, we have for any $1\le i \le k$, 
$$I_i+\bigcap_{\substack{1\le j \le k\\j\ne i}}I_j=R. $$
So, given $a_1, \dots, a_k, a_{k+1}\in R$, there exists some $a\in R$ such that
$$a\equiv a_i\mod I_i\quad(1\le i\le k)$$
and $a$ is unique mod. $\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^k I_j$.

Can you end the inductive step?

*Some more details*:

Note that if $J=\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^k I_j $, we have $J+I_{k+1}=R$. 
So we have to find $A\in R$ such that \begin{cases}A\equiv a& \mkern-12mu\bmod J\\A\equiv a_{k+1},&\mkern-12mu\bmod I_{k+1}.\end{cases}
which is possible by the case $k=2$, and the solution is unique modulo $J\cap I_{k+1} =\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^{k+1} I_j$.

Comment: Nope, can't unfortunately.

Comment: This comes down to the case $k=2$.

Comment: I really can't see it.

Comment: I've added some details.

Comment: Now I understand the proof. However, I don't see what uniqueness modulo $\cap I_i$ has to do with anything

Comment: That's right. The uniqueness is an addendum, as stated in Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. II. And,  in a sense, the hypotheses  therein are simpler: for any $i, j$, $i\ne j$, $I_i+I_j=R$.

Comment: Just a small thing: you have a typo in the next to last line; it should be $J + I_{k+1} = R$.

Comment: Oh! yes. I have typos more than often. Thanks for pointing it. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Cauchy I added an answer which often helps make the proof more obvious..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ It is easy if we view the solutions as "vectors" in the product ring $\,  (R/I_1,\ldots, R/I_k).\,$ Then every such congruence is solvable iff the natural image of $R$ in the product ring is onto iff the image contains all unit vectors $e_j$ with $1$ in the $j$'th component and $0$ in all others, since they *span*, e.g. $$(a_1,a_2,a_3) = a_1(1,0,0)+a_2(0,1,0)+ a_3(0,0,1) = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2+ a_3 e_3$$

But the hypotheses imply that unit vector systems are solveable, since by hypothes $\,a+b = 1\,$ for $\,a\in I_j,\ b\in I_i, \forall\, i\neq j$ so $\,e_j := 1\!-\!a = b\,$  $\,\Rightarrow\,e_j\equiv 1\pmod{I_j},\ $ $e_j\equiv 0\pmod{I_i},\forall\,i\ne j$

**Remark** $ $ The classical CRT formula for integers is a special case, where the unit vectors are constructed by the formula

$\qquad  e_j := M_j(M_j^{-1} \bmod m_j)\,$ where $M_j$ is the product of all moduli except $m_j$

Note $\,M_j \equiv 1\pmod{m_j}\,$ and $\,M_j\equiv 0\,$ mod other moduli since they divide $\,M_j$